# How to get rows (by id) of ids that appears in the dataframe in time period of 2 months?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Does anybody know how I do the following (in Python)?

I have a pandas DataFrame in which I have the following values: date (dd/mm/yy), id (int), label (values 0 or 1).

I want to identify (and keep it in a new dataframe), for each id, if it appears again in the dataframe, in the time period of 2 months. and what was its label for each appears (if occurs).

sample data:

```
    date            id    label
1   01/01/2019     123      1
2   02/01/2019     111      0
3   28/02/2019     123      0
4   03/03/2019     123      1
5   01/05/2019     111      1
6   03/06/2019     111      0
7   03/07/2019     123      1 
8   04/07/2019     222      1
```

expected output:

```
    date            id    label
1   01/01/2019     123      1
2   28/02/2019     123      0
3   03/03/2019     123      1
4   01/05/2019     111      1
5   03/06/2019     111      0
```

Thanks!

Comment: kindly share sample data and expected output

Comment: It's not "efficient" or "memory" safe but you could just form the crosses date x (date[:,None] - date[None, :]) or something like that. Then you mask on the timedelta being less than two months. You will get a row of indices for each date row. I'm not 100% if you actually want that but I think you do. 

So to be clear you are really looking at a 2d-grid of dates. 

I would post the code to create the data frame you want. 

You can also just do it in a for loop without the fancy broadcasting. Better memory, less fast etc.

You might also be able to a group.transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the task involves date calculations, I converted *date* column
to *datetime*, so they are printed in *yyyy-mm-dd* format.

Define the following function, generating "second level" group numbers,
for each "first level" group (grouped by *id*):

```
def grNo(dat):
    gNo = 1
    endDate = dat.iloc[0] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)
    res = []
    for d in dat:
        if d >= endDate:
            endDate = d + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)
            gNo += 1
        res.append(gNo)
    return res
```

Then use it as the second level of grouping:

```
df.groupby(['id', df.groupby('id').date.transform(grNo)])\
    .filter(lambda grp: len(grp) > 1)
```

Filtering removes (second level) groups containing only a single row.

The result, for your data, is:

```
        date   id  label
1 2019-01-01  123      1
3 2019-02-28  123      0
5 2019-05-01  111      1
6 2019-06-03  111      0
```

Note that this result does not include row for *03/03/2019, 123, 1*,
because:

- The first group for *id == 123* contains rows for *2019-01-01*
  and *2019-02-28*.
- Row with *id == 123* and *date = 2019-03-03* creates the **next** group
  (it is more than 2 months apart from the first row in the previous
  group), but this group was filtered out as containing only one row.

So in my opinion your expected result is wrong in this detail.

## Edit

Or maybe you want to keep rows with same *id* as long as dates of
**consecutive rows** are no more that 2 months apart?

In such case the solution is simpler:

Define the function generating second level group numbers as:

```
def grNo2(dat):
    return (dat > dat.shift(1) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)).cumsum()
```

Then use it:

```
df.groupby(['id', df.groupby('id').date.transform(grNo2)])\
    .filter(lambda grp: len(grp) > 1)
```

In this case the result is:

```
        date   id  label
1 2019-01-01  123      1
3 2019-02-28  123      0
4 2019-03-03  123      1
5 2019-05-01  111      1
6 2019-06-03  111      0
```